# Git thinks a commit message is a command not found

Tags: git, command-line, zsh

I'm following along a Udacity course right now and after typing this:

```
g cmp "adds string.replace() quiz"
```

I got the error messages

```
git:3: command not found: quiz
git:80: command not found: quiz
git:84: command not found: quiz
```

now any git command I type in returns

```
git:1: command not found: quiz
```

Will undoing a commit solve the issue? Couldn't find anything like this doing a search. I am using Zsh, for the record.

My git aliases come from this repo: 
https://github.com/Prelang/g

Comment: Have you tried a regular `git commit -m "..."`?

Comment: @Nyx I did! I forgot to mention that. Tried many regular commands, seems anything git will do it.

Comment: Can you use some software that handles git commits for you (e.g. sourcetree)? Maybe the software cleans up any weird state that your git may be in.

Comment: have you tried single quotes: `g cmp 'adds string.replace() quiz'`?

Comment: It's back to normal now but I had actually tried that and it hadn't worked either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`g cmp`](https://github.com/Prelang/g/blob/master/g.zsh#L340) is alias for [`git commit` with message](https://github.com/Prelang/g/blob/master/g.zsh#L406-L409), maybe the `()` were not will interpreted in that context.

Try (in a new shell) the same command without `()`.

```
g cmp "adds string.replace quiz"
```

As [Nils Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636626/nils-werner) points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253872/6309), single quotes *should* have prevented the interpretation of `()`, but there might be another issue with the alias definition.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I don't suppose there's a way to be able to include the `()` without it getting confused?

Comment: Basically, this means there is a bug in that zsh code. There is no reason is should not be able to handle an arbitrary string as a commit message.

Comment: Will have to look into that as well!

Answer (score 5):

Zsh [interprets some aspects of the contents of double quotes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html). To make sure zsh treats your string like a raw string and does no interpretation you should use single quotes:

```
git commit -m 'adds string.replace() quiz'
```

Note you might have double quotes in your git alias which might be interfering, too.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll have to take a closer look at my beloved aliases.